# Able to import constants using OmniFaces but not ImportHandler#importClass()

Tags: jsf, el, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

The following bean loads eagerly e.g.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class EnumConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        System.out.println("Testing 123...");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().addELContextListener(

            new ELContextListener() {

                @Override
                public void contextCreated(ELContextEvent event) {

                    System.out.println("Testing 456...");
                    event.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass(
                        "foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.YesOrNo");
                    //importHandler.importPackage(
                    //  "foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.preference");
                    Class<?> clazz = importHandler.resolveClass("YesOrNo");
                    System.out.println("clazz = " + clazz);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

> 21:26:48,703 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-4) Testing 123...
>
> 21:39:11,976 INFO  [stdout] (default task-9) Testing 456...

I set a breakpoint and I can see that "foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.YesOrNo" is properly entered into `classNameMap`.  However a second entry is made in `notAClass`, indicating that `YesOrNo` was not found, which is not good.

```
importHandler = {javax.el.ImportHandler@15909}
    classNameMap = {java.util.HashMap@15910} size = 1
        [0] = {java.util.HashMap$Node@15923}"YesOrNo" -> "foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.YesOrNo"
    classMap = {java.util.HashMap@15911} size = 0
    staticNameMap = {java.util.HashMap@15912} size = 0
    notAClass = {java.util.HashSet@15913} size = 1
        [0] = {java.lang.String@15030}"foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.YesOrNo"
    packages = {java.util.ArrayList@15914} size = 1
        [0] = {java.lang.String@15926}"java.lang"
```

> 21:39:11,976 INFO  [stdout] (default task-18) clazz = null

Here's the JavaDoc for `ImportHandler#resolveClass()`, which seems to indicate I am using it correctly (without package name):

> public Class resolveClass(String name)
>
> Resolve a class name.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `name` - The name of the class (without package name) to be resolved.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ```
> If the class has been imported previously, with importClass(java.lang.String) or
> importPackage(java.lang.String), then its Class instance. Otherwise null.
> ```
>
> **Throws:**
>
> ```
> ELException - if the class is abstract or is an interface, or not public.
> ```

Referring to the EL 3.0 spec.:

> **1.22.2 Imports of Packages, Classes, and Static Fields**
>
> Either a class or a package can be explicitly imported into the EL evaluation environment. Importing a package imports all the classes in the package. The classes that can be imported are restricted to the classes that can be loaded by the current class loader.
>
> By default, the following packages are imported by the EL environment.
>
> ```
>                     java.lang.*
> ```
>
> A static field can also be imported statically. A statically imported static field can be referenced by the field name, without the classname.
>
> The imports of packages, classes, and static fields are handled by the ImportHandler in the ELContext.

Here's the ImportHandler relevant code[(see GitHub)](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-el-api_spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/el/ImportHandler.java#L176):

```
private Class<?> getClassFor(String className) {
    if (!notAClass.contains(className)) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(className, false, getClass().getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            notAClass.add(className);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using `<o:importConstants>` of OmniFaces works just fine:

```
<o:importConstants type="foo.bar.business.model.enumeration.YesOrNo"/>
```

Here's the OmniFaces approach, using a TagHandler [(see GitHub)](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/taghandler/ImportConstants.java#L164):

```
/**
 * Convert the given type, which should represent a fully qualified name, to a concrete {@link Class} instance.
 * @param type The fully qualified name of the class.
 * @return The concrete {@link Class} instance.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException When it is missing in the classpath.
 */
static Class<?> toClass(String type) { // Package-private so that ImportFunctions can also use it.
    try {
    return Class.forName(type, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Perhaps it's an inner enum which is specified as com.example.SomeClass.SomeEnum.
        // Let's be lenient on that although the proper type notation should be com.example.SomeClass$SomeEnum.
        int i = type.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            try {
                return toClass(
                    new StringBuilder(type.substring(0, i)).append('$').append(type.substring(i + 1)).toString());
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                // Just continue to the IllegalArgumentException on the original ClassNotFoundException.
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(ERROR_MISSING_CLASS, type), e);
    }
}
```

So `javax.el.ImportHandler` invokes `getClass().getClassLoader()` whereas `org.omnifaces.taghandler.ImportConstants` invokes `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`.

Shouldn't `javax.el.ImportHandler` use the current thread class loader so that it can load classes in WEB-INF/classes?  Does `javax.el.ImportHandler` satisfy the EL spec. requirement that *the classes that can be imported are restricted to the classes that can be loaded by the current class loader*?  I don't know whether or not current class loader means the thread context class loader associated with the current thread.

Comment: Submitted [WFLY-4023](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4023)